# Error loading operating system: on only one pc

Tags: windows-xp, acronis-trueimage

I've an old industrial PC with Windows XP SP1. This PC has a 60GB IBM HDD. I've got a second HDD of that type.

I did clone an backup image from this system using true image to this *new* HDD (all partitions including MBR). After installing it to this system, it wouldn't boot. Error message just after POST `Error loading operating system`. Nothing more. Bios correctly detects it's boot device.

I redid the whole process. Same thing. I did attach this drive to another PC through some USB-IDE adapter (with that I've done the cloning). Boot from USB. Windows XP is booting up.

What could be wrong here? It's the same type of HDD which was previously installed. The system and all the drivers on that image is designed for this system, BIOS detects it as the same drive as before. The image was correctly written by true image (verification successful) and this HDD failing to boot in its target system, does boot fine in another PC. What could be wrong here? Thank you

Comment: Try a BIOS reset.

Comment: Thank you. But it didn‘t work. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. For reasons unknown the BIOS detects this particular HDD with wrong settings for cylinders, heads and sectors. Name, serial number and capacity are correctly detected. And another HDD with the same part number is detected correctly altogether.

If the CHS settings are configured manually, the PC is able to boot from this HDD as well.

But why the HDD is falsely detected regarding its CHS settings by the BIOS is opaque. Thanks anyway.